# Get url of current prestashop page using smarty

Tags: smarty, prestashop-1.6

I have two shops
toorakcomputerservices.com.au and malverncomputerservices.com.au

I am using multishop features. All the data seems fine but the cms pages that i have modified in .tpl are shared by these two sites.
My copyright notice is

Copyright © toorakcomputerservices.com.au 1997-2015 in

/public_html/themes/default-bootstrap/modules/blockcms/blockcms.tpl

but this is shared by both sites. I want different copyrights for them.

I thought i could use if else statement to check which site is trying to access the page and display the notice accordingly.

```
{assign var="url" value=$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI}
{if $url=="http://toorakcomputerservices.com.au}
<div>
        Copyright &copy; toorakcomputerservices.com.au 1997-2015 
</div>
{else}
<div>
        Copyright &copy; malverncomputerservices.com.au 1997-2015 
</div>
{/if}
```

But this shows error. I tried to find other solutions on the forums but they all show errors. I am not much familiar with smarty so i need help. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
{if $smarty.server.HTTP_HOST=="toorakcomputerservices.com.au"}
  <div>
    Copyright &copy; toorakcomputerservices.com.au 1997-2015 
  </div>
{else}
  <div>
    Copyright &copy; malverncomputerservices.com.au 1997-2015 
  </div>
{/if}
```

But I think this would be more elegant:

```
<div>
  Copyright &copy; {$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST} 1997-2015 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was just perfect. I used the recommended elegant version. :)

Answer (score 0):

its better create new module with register header hook or display header hook, and from the hook assign current shop url to smarty, you can use the assigned variable inside your tpl

```
public function install(){
  return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('displayHeader');
}

public function hookdisplayHeader($params){
 /// here assign shop url to smarty
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks @Abdulla, I used yenshirak ' s method and it worked. I am going to try what you said just to learn how to do it so i can use it in my project.